# Accessing two drop down menu's in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, drop-down-menu, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape this web site: http://surge.srcc.lsu.edu/s1.html
But it is always selecting the last value even though the loop is running through the correct 1st drop down but then it bugs out and switched to the last value and the last value of the second drop down. I think the error is in loading the second drop down box after picking the first? I can't seem to resolve it though.

```
# importing libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://surge.srcc.lsu.edu/s1.html")

# definition for switching frames
def frame_switch(css_selector):
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector))  

frame_switch("iframe")

html_source = driver.page_source  
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="storm_name"]')
options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

optionsList = []

for option in options: #iterate over the options, place attribute value in list
    optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
   
for optionValue in optionsList: # looping through the first drop down
    print ("starting loop on option %s" % optionValue)
    option.click()
    html_source = driver.page_source  
    time.sleep(3)
    
    element_year = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="year"]')
    options_year = element_year.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    optionsList2 = []
    
    for option in options_year: #iterate and make list for second drop down
        optionsList2.append(option.get_attribute("value"))
        
    for optionValue in optionsList2: # loop through Second drop down
        print ("starting loop on option %s" % optionValue)
        option.click()
        time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [Select](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html) instead, then select each option by index. See code below

```
html_source = driver.page_source
nameSelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="storm_name"]'))
stormCount = len(nameSelect.options)

for i in range(1, stormCount):
    print("starting loop on option storm " + nameSelect.options[i].text)
    nameSelect.select_by_index(i)
    time.sleep(3)
    html_source = driver.page_source

    yearSelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="year"]'))
    yearCount = len(yearSelect.options)
    for j in range(1, yearCount):
        print("starting loop on option year " + yearSelect.options[j].text)
        yearSelect.select_by_index(j)
        time.sleep(3)
        html_source = driver.page_source
```

Comment: This is actually not a solution to his problem since values are loaded with JavaScript when the user selects a storm. Therefore calling`element.click()` is needed.

Comment: @Krazor could you try my code and tell me what is the problem? I'm confused what you are talking about.

Comment: Woops. I misread that, my bad, Sorry. Nice Solution, cleaner than mine.

Comment: Thanks so much this was helpful and much cleaner than my code!

Comment: @ChrisCornett your welcome. By the way, could you accept the answer so we can close this question?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code.
I rewrote it and added some commments.

```
# importing libraries
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://surge.srcc.lsu.edu/s1.html")

# definition for switching frames
def frame_switch(css_selector):
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector))  

frame_switch("iframe")

html_source = driver.page_source  #Why do you even need this?
                                  #I am assuming you are following a tutorial, however this line could be omitted
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="storm_name"]')
options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

for option in options[1:]: #Using [1:] alias List Slicing will skip the first element in options which is -1 ("Choose a storm")
    print ("Currently looping over Storm {}.".format(option.get_attribute("value")))
    option.click()
    time.sleep(2) #It would be a lot better to use explicit or implicit wait but thats for another day.

    element_year = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="year"]')
    options_year = element_year.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

    for option in options_year[1:]: #Same as above with ("Choose a Year")
        print ("Currently looping over Year {}.".format(option.get_attribute("value")))
        time.sleep(2) #Same as above
        option.click()
```

This will do what you want. However I advise you do to multiple things:

1. Learn about [Python List Slicing](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/).
2. Use logging/print in your code in order to check values and contens of lists and dicts. The repeating `-1` should have seemed fishy to you as well as the fact that option always pointed at `Wilma`.
3. Clean up your imports and code on a regular basis. If a variable is never referenced anywhwere it usually means it is irrelevant. (Could also be imported from another namespace though, watch out for this.)

Good luck and keep learning.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. I will make sure to keep these tip in mind.